# getpwnam getpwnam_r

Tags: c, linux, data-structures, systems-programming

I am trying to update a password structure in a function. 
This function gets a pointer to password structure, into which 
I have to update details.

I get a `struct passwd*` to a function as an argument and my requirement is to update it's members to someother user's(user2) information and caller of this function should have all these updated details.

I tried following, can you please help me by suggesting what is an ideal way to do it.

My function is like this:

```
struct passwd* myfunc(struct passwd *pw)
```

To this `pw`, I have to update details.

> Try1:

Using `getpwnam()` get details of user2 into passed `struct passwd *pw`.

```
pw = getpwnam("user2");
return pw;
```

Does not work, as we are not updating pw members rather we are just pointing `pw` to some other struct, pointer members of `pw`, still point to older data. 
And thus parent of `myfunc()` does not get updated details.

We have to write into members.

> Try2:

Using `getpwnam()` get details of user2 into a temp `struct passwd*`.
Do a `memcpy(pw, temppasswd, sizeof(struct passwd))`

Does not work as `memcpy` is a shallow copy and consequent `getpwnam()` (although the return is not given to `temppasswd`) will over write static buffer area, and `pw` may have different values.

> Try3:

Tried `getpwnam_r()` which writes details into buffer passed as an argument to it rather than into a static data area (like `getpwnam`).

Can not use this, as I don't have `pw`, I have `*pw`.
So, I can not pass address of memory allocated to `pw` to `getpwnam_r`.

> Try 4:

I can do member by member copy in Try2, but it can result in memory leaks if I don't free `pw` structure pointer members before copying data into them.

Is there any other way to copy details to passed `pw*` without free-ing all struct `pw*` pointer members.

It is a bit confusing, I hope I make sense to someone.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the first two alternatives as `*pw = *getpwnam("user2");`. It's still a shallow copy though.

As for your problem, if you can change the prototype to `struct passwd* myfunc(struct passwd **pw)` then you could allocate the structure and all needed fields yourself. Then have a separate function that the user must call to free all allocated data.

Comment: No, I can not change function prototype as there are many callers. And I dont want to change all those functions :(

Comment: @Ram Then you unfortunately have to live with shallow copying and static buffers.